# Google Cloud DNS - Multiple TXT Records + TTL

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I have a small problem with Google Cloud DNS.

Here it is:

```
{
    "kind": "dns#resourceRecordSet",
    "name": "example.com.",
    "type": "TXT",
    "ttl": 86400,
    "rrdatas": [
        "\"v=spf1 a mx include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:_spf.google.com include:smtp1.uservoice.com -all\"",
        "\"google-site-verification=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""
    ]
    }
```

But when I dig the domain, that's what I get:

```
example.com.        5   IN  TXT "google-site-verification=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
example.com.        5   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:_spf.google.com include:smtp1.uservoice.com -all"
```

The TTL won't set itself at anything else than 5 - and only for TXT records.

Anybody had the same problem?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it. Do you still have this issue?

Comment: I have moved to Amazon Route 53 since then. Maybe the problem got fixed.